# How can I import variables out of views.py in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am a complete beginner to Django and relatively new to Python, although I'm comfortable with the basic syntax of the language. I've made a post form in Django that takes my input and assigns it to a variable in my views.py file after filtering it, like so:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']

    form = NameForm()    
    return render(request, './index.html', {'form': form})
```

'name' is my variable being stored from my NameForm() form, which was made and imported from a separate form file. My issue begins when I need the 'name' variable to be imported into another .py file. The first and obvious method would be to import views into my other file, but this doesn't work.

For some reason I don't know, being a Django newbie, importing a views.py file works perfectly unless you have to run that individual .py file, then it gives the error:

> "ImportError: cannot import name 'views'"

The obvious response to this would be asking if I'm referencing the wrong directory, which I know I'm not, since the urls.py file works. I also know nothing is inherently wrong with my views file since it routes my urls properly.

So I don't know where to go from here. My temporary solution has been to bring my entire other file relying on the 'name' variable into my views file. It works as it should, but won't work as I begin expanding my site.

I appreciate any help in advance. I can supplement more help if need be, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: post the stacktrace and also the file where this error is occuring

Comment: You shouldn't _run_ a Python program that imports Django specific components outside Django. Write a custom management command instead. It will automatically set up syspath for you. Even in that case I wouldn't suggest importing views as it should be the other way around (i.e. write a helper module and import from that in both your views and your management commands).

Answer (score 0):

After 36 hours with this problem, I came up with a simple solution. Instead of trying to import views.py to my other file, I just imported that file into views.py, and when a post request is submitted it calls my function on the remote file with the name as a parameter. I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it is much more elegant than the previous one. I just needed a good night's rest to think that one out.